# Using an iterator for a set of type Object?

Tags: java, iterator

Okay, so I'm supposed to implement a set that contains elements of type Object **with no duplicates** which means that I need to compare each new element with the previous elements in the set. The set has its own class and has a method for inserting a new element.

My question is: How do I use the iterator I wrote below to compare all the entries in the set with the proposed element to add?

```
class SetIterator implements MyIterator {
    private ArraySet arr;  //ArraySet is the name of the Set class
    private int n;

    SetIterator(ArraySet myArraySet)
    {
        arr = myArraySet;
        n = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() 
    {
        return (n <= arr.size());
    }

    @Override
    public Object next()
    {
        if (hasNext())
            return arr[n++];
    }   
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to accomplish here. Is this homework?

Comment: Got a bunch of bugs there too -  hasNext should be n < ...size(), need to throw NoSuchElementException if the element doesn't exist, and you can't subscript an object with [] - probably want to use a .get method.

Comment: Yes, I just want an example on how to use that iterator instead of a for loop or a while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need something like this in ArraySet.java.

```
public Iterator iterator()
{
    return new SetIterator(this);
}

public boolean add(Object o)
{
    for (Object item : this)
        if (o.equals(next)) return false;
    }
    // add code to put o in the array
    return true;
}
```

The `for` loop is translated by the compiler to something like this:

```
Iterator it = this.iterator();
while (it.hasNext())
{
    Object item = it.next();
    if (o.equals(next)) return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of `Set` should guarantee no-duplication rather than the `Iterator`.

That is, your `Set.add()` and its constructor with Collection as argument should guarantee no-duplication. 
The Iterator just implements `hasNext()`, `next()`, and `remove()`.

If `Iterator` takes care of duplication checking, your Set will violate `java.util.Set` contract. Moreover, the Iterator will take two responsibilities—checking duplication and traversing, that violates “Single Responsibily Principle”.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, I just want an example on how to use that iterator instead of a for loop or a while loop.

You pretty much have to use some kind of loop to use a `Iterator`.  Here is the basic pattern:

```
Iterator it = ... // instantiate the iterator
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Object obj = it.next();
    ... // do something with obj
}
```

If the collection object (e.g. your set of objects) implements `Iterable` then you can use the new `for` loop syntax; e.g.

```
for (Object obj : yourSet) {
    ... // do something with obj
}
```

Of course, there are other ways to express this, but they *all* involve (somewhere) a loop of some kind to pull the objects from the iterator.